# Remove complete row from dataframe if begins with certain word: R

Tags: r

I am struck with the problem, where i want to blank out the row, if it begins certain word, from below example, i want to blank out the entries which begins with "error"

Input:

```
TESTNumber
errorCode404errorMessage
TESTNumber
TESTNumber
TESTNumber
TESTNumber
TESTNumber
TESTNumber
TESTNumber
TESTNumber
TESTNumber
TESTNumber
TESTNumber
TESTNumber
TESTNumber
TESTNumber
TESTNumber
TESTNumber
errorCode404errorMessage
errorCode404errorMessage
errorCode404errorMessage
```

Any guidance in this direction will be great support.

Comment: What did you try, and how did it fail? This is probably a duplicate.

Comment: Consider edit your question after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and adding more information. As tripleee said, this looks like a duplicate to begin with, so you should maybe start with searching for your answer. The related links on the side of your question is a good place to start.

Comment: try `grepl()` to get the indices where condition matches and then remove the indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick data:

```
df <- data.frame("var1" = 1:2, "var2" = c("testest", "errorTtest"))

> df
  var1       var2
1    1    testest
2    2 errorTtest
```

Now use `grepl()` with the pattern `"^error.*"` to get the positions of all rows with `error` in the beginning of `var2`, use `which` with `-` to delete them from the data.

```
> df[-(which(grepl("^error.*", df$var2))),]
  var1    var2
1    1 testest
```

Comment: `df[!grepl("^error", df$var2),]`